# Maven create jar out of folder

Tags: maven, jar, build, war

Hi i would like to do a simple task within a maven build.
This task should go to a specific folder and should pack the contain of the folder into a jar file. (just like zip everything into jar)

How can i do that

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

You could specify the source directory in assembly descriptor as follows:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>[source directory path]</directory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

and pack it as a jar:

```
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
```